# Listing of products in search results of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I’ve the problem that in search results the products are not listed properly.

In the search suggester (we use Amasty Extension) everything is fine when i search for term „Warm up“. The most relevant products are listed first.

https://www.kunert.de

However when i hit enter and go for the full result then the relevant products having „Warm up“ in the product name are listed on third and much lower positions. Other products having just part of the search term in the product name appear first.

https://www.kunert.de/catalogsearch/result/?q=Warm+up

Search weight for product name is already 10.

Is it possible somehow to influence this?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your issue i will suggest to added Search Synonyms group for word so its better results for as per like.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/search-synonyms.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have an example in mind which we could use for the synonyms?